# merging dataframes (python pandas)

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two dataframes df1 [df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiUUh.png) and df2 [df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfKCy.png)
I want to merge them using python pandas without creating the Cartesian product.Sample output would look like this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ewp.png) How should I do it?

Currently,I am using
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='id',how='left') but it's giving me cross product.The resultant dataframe df3 contains 14 records 6 for id=1 and 8 for id=2.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not use pictures in your questions. You can read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need an additional key for help, create by `cumcount`

```
df1['Helpkey']=df1.groupby('id').cumcount()
df2['Helpkey']=df2.groupby('id').cumcount()

df1.merge(df2,how='left').drop('Helpkey',1)
```

Comment: Thank You!! It worked when I replaced how='left' with how='outer'..I really appreciate your help